# How to filter pandas DF on concatenation of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

How to filter pandas DF on concatenation of columns?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product_name': ['laptop', 'laptop', 'printer', 'tablet', 'desk', 'chair', 'chair', 'chair'],
        'price': [1200, 1000, 150, 300, 450, 200, 100, 120],
        'color': ['white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'brown', 'red', 'grey', 'black']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

There's a list of conditions:
`[('laptop', 'black'), ('chair', 'red'), ('chair', 'grey')]`

How do I filter it to only return rows that match those conditions? Assume it's a big df with many more columns, with thousands of rows and thousands of conditions like that.

Comment: a multiindex looks like a good fit for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a tuple column named `condition`, using the `product_name` and the `color`:

```
df['condition'] = list(zip(df.product_name, df.color))
```

Then it is just a matter of checking whether the tuples contained in this column match any of the conditions listed in the `list_of_conditions`:

```
list_of_conditions = [('laptop', 'black'), ('chair', 'red'), ('chair', 'grey')]
df[df.condition.isin(list_of_conditions)]
```

For the example dataframe provided in your post, this snippet returns:

```
    product_name    price   color   condition
1   laptop          1000    black   (laptop, black)
5   chair           200     red     (chair, red)
6   chair           100     grey    (chair, grey)
```